# JAX-WS endpoint publishing issue with JAXB param in web method

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-ws

I can publish the Endpoint without problems when my one and only web method has a String parameter. But if I change the param to a JAXB class, I always run into a `IllegalArgumentException: argument contains null`. I generated the JAXB class with the **xjc** tool. I also ran a debugger through it, but I'm not able to figure out where the issue comes from. I only know the issue appears while marshalling process happens. Any idea what it can be or what I can do furthermore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it. Just [avoid anonymous types in XML schema](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-avoid-anonymous-types/index.html). After generating JAXB classes via **xjc** my service endpoint interface started as expected.